# Is there any USB modem that is supported by default in Ubuntu?

Tags: usb-modem

I need to buy an USB modem and also want to use it in Ubuntu. It there any modem available that is supported by default and can be used without any hack?

Comment: You need to check with each manufacturer.

Comment: Most, if not all of the USB 3G modem from Optus, Vodafone, Testra that you can buy now works in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about others but I can tell about a `USB Modem` that definitely works with  Ubuntu. I am attaching a photo of it.

[image]

**Description**

`LAVA 730G USB Modem`

- Supports Ubuntu, MAC, Windows..
- You can insert any prepaid SIM..
- Comes with setup in `.deb`, `.exe` and `binary` format so you need to install drivers which is stored in its small memory card.

I've found this very useful. You can also give it a try..